# mssql select all nvarchar with wrong encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding

I am working with a old database where someone didn't encode the data the right way before inserting it into the database. which result in text like

"Wrong t�xt" (in my case the '�' is a ø).

I am looking for a way to find all rows where the column contains data like this, so i can correct it.

So far i tried using regex like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ([colm] not like '[a-zA-Z\s]%')
```

but no matter what i do, i can't find a way to select only the ones containing the '�'

a search like

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE ([colm] like '%�%')
```

won't return anything either. (tried it, just in cases).

I been search for this on Google and here on Stackoverflow, but either there is no one having this problem, or I am searching for the wrong thing.

So if someone would be so kind to help me with this, I would be really happy.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should look at the value of `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [colm])` in the erroneous cases, to see what the bytes *really* are. Notably, if you're looking at values stored in a `VARCHAR` column that your client decodes as UTF-8, the text will not actually contain a literal � character, as this is just the replacement character displayed when it can't make sense of the encoding. Prior to 2019, SQL Server itself had no support for UTF-8, so it would be unusual to have this problem when looking at the data with Management Studio, but you might be using something else.

Comment: If the column is Unicode, and the character is a literal �, it will show up as `FDFF` (`U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`).

Comment: Seems like the best approach, after my attempt failed @JeroenMostert .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the character in the string really is `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` (�), and it's not displayed as a replacement character because there are actually other bytes in there that can't be decoded properly, you can find it with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [colm] LIKE N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2
```

Or (to avoid any further issues with encoding mangling characters)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [colm] LIKE N'%' + NCHAR(0xfffd) + N'%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2
```

Unicode is required because � does not exist in any single-byte collation, and a binary collation is required because the regular collations treat � as if it did not occur in strings at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WHERE [colm] not like N'%[a-zA-Z]%'
```

Of course, this should return values with numbers, spaces, and punctuation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i tried it out. it all the colm where the text is anything else but a letter. but my problem is i need to find column where the symbol is mixed in with the letters.

Comment: @dach . . . Then add `and column like N'%[a-zA-Z]%'` to be sure the column has at least one letter.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeroen mentioned, using a `binary` seems to be the way to go. Personally I would suggest using [`NGrams4k`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) here, but I built a quick tally table instead that does the job:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT V.Colm
FROM (VALUES(N'Wrong t�xt" (in my case the ''�'' is a ø)'),
            (N'This string is ok'))V(colm)
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(V.Colm) >= T.I
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.Colm,T.I,1))) SS(C) 
GROUP BY V.colm
HAVING COUNT(CASE CONVERT(binary(2),SS.C) WHEN 0xFDFF THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: This seems overkill -- if you *are* looking for a literal `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, what should suffice is `WHERE colm LIKE N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2` (or `LIKE N'%' + NCHAR(0xFFFD) + N'%'`, to avoid further encoding issues while copy-pasting), to force a binary comparison (non-binary collations will ignore �).

Comment: You should post that as an answer then @JeroenMostert :)

Comment: This indead seems like the best solution. Post an answer.

Comment: I was actually waiting on OP to confirm or deny that they've actually got the replacement character in their strings (by looking at the binary representation), and it's not an artifact of decoding a string that doesn't actually contain such a character (in which case searching for it won't help).

Comment: @JeroenMostert sry. was sleeping. i tied to look at the binary representation. and can't seem to find it there.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace occurences of the `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` (�) and compare it with the original value:

```
SELECT *
, CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), t.colm) = CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), t.colm), 0xFDFF, 0x) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EncodingCorrect
FROM (
    SELECT N'Wrong t�xt" (in my case the ''�'' is a ø)' AS colm
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Correct text'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Wrong t?xt" (in my case the ''?'' is a ø)'
) t
```

**@Jeroen Mostert**'s suggestion `WHERE colm LIKE N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2` seems like the better and more readable solution.

Comment: This will not actually work correctly, because it searches for any occurrence of the bytes `0xFDFF`, regardless of whether they occur on a code point boundary. This means that, e.g. `0x30FDFF00` (which is `U+FD30 ARABIC LIGATURE SHEEN WITH MEEM INITIAL FORM` followed by `U+00FF LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS`) will also match this, even though these are two valid characters. Admittedly it's not the most likely sequence of characters... But it's worth pointing out anyway, because "boundary shifts" are a common source of trouble processing binary content in T-SQL.

Comment: So it turns out the the where clause made by jeroen mostert is working. I would like, if you could leave a answer @JeroenMostert.